# Add product count to toolbar.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, toolbar

I want to add product count to the toolbar.phtml. The current code results in a blank page. Can anyone suggest an edit to get it working?

```
<?php <p class="amount">
                    <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </p>  ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `<?php` and `?>`

```
<p class="amount">
<?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
<?php endif; ?>
</p>
```